# Drop connection for users that left/closed the page

Tags: javascript, java, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a script for a post view counter using firebase.
The problem is that firebase is almost always maxed out with 100 simultaneous connections, even though only 20 people are connected right now (according to google analytics).
So I want to implement a statement that will solve this problem, but I don't know how.

The scripts:

```html
<script type='text/javascript'>
  window.setTimeout(function() {
    document.body.className = document.body.className.replace('loading', '');
  }, 10);
</script>

<script src='https://cdn.firebase.com/v0/firebase.js' type='text/javascript'></script>

<script>
$.each($('a[name]'), function(i, e) {
  var elem = $(e).parent().find('#postviews').addClass('mbtloading');
  var blogStats = new Firebase("MY - FIREBASE - ID" + $(e).attr('name'));
  blogStats.once(value, function(snapshot) {
    var data = snapshot.val();
    var isnew = false;
    if (data == null) {
      data = {};
      data.value = 0;
      data.url = window.location.href;
      data.id = $(e).attr('name');
      isnew = true;
    }
    elem.removeClass('mbtloading').text(data.value);
    data.value++;
    if (window.location.pathname != '/') {
      if (isnew)
        blogStats.set(data);
      else
        blogStats.child('value').set(data.value);
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

For some reason one post also shows the wrong count (the count whenever someone presses on "more info") but that's not a pressing issue.

Comment: Where did you get that URL for the firebase CDN? It's not [what the docs suggest](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#delay-sdks-cdn)…

Comment: It's the Project ID of my Database and in the ruleset I added "{ "rules": { ".read": true, ".write": true  }}"
Edit: Oh you mean the src? I got the code from a different blog and adjusted it a bit without paying attention to the CDN url

Comment: Many blog posts and tutorials concerning firebase are old and even date back to the time where firebase did not belong to google… I think you should try to stick to the official docs as much as you can.

Comment: could someone help me adjust the script? I can't seem to figure out how to implement the newer firebase urls.